# Why are my render results not coming out the same as viewport?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, shaders

When I render my scene, it renders the solid view shading instead rendered view shading.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use **OpenGL Render** instead:

[image: OpenGL Render]

It renders what you see in 3D-Viewport.

[image: OpenGL Render]

*Blender 2.80 beta* doesn't bring this function back, it might become available soon.